# Inserting parameter to a web service call in service stack

Tags: servicestack, basic-authentication

Lets say I have the Hello World web service defined, from the Service Stack examples, but instead of just calling it as /hello/{name}, I want to be able to call it as /hello/{name}/id, where I define id to be a separate parameter (by storing it in refId, within a CustomUserSession).

In other words, I want to split the authentication and the actual web service call into 2 parts, but I don't want to expose this id in the actual web service call, because this is private, only within my system. How would I go about doing this? My ideal workflow is:

- client calls web service : /hello/{name}
- authentication happens. As part of this authentication, I get hold of this secret id
- I now call the web service as /hello/{name}/id

It's almost as if I want to call a web service from within another web service.

I apologize if this seems like a misguided question, but how can I go about achieving this workflow?

Thanks

Comment: How will the response be different for /hello/{name}/id compared to /hello{name} ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend taking a look at [ServiceStack routing](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing). Your service will only be called if it matches an existing route (or uses a [pre-defined route](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/#predefinedroutes)) which means if you only had:

```
 [Route("/hello/{name}")]
```

It wont match `/hello/{name}/{id}` and your service wont be called. To match that route you can either have an explicit route for it, e.g:

```
 [Route("/hello/{name}/{id}")]
```

But this is public info which you're saying you would like to hide. The alternative is to use a wildcard route, e.g:

```
 [Route("/hello/{name*}")]
```

Which matches any `/hello/*` route inc. `/hello`, `/hello/foo`, `/hello/foo/id`, `/hello/foo/id/and/more/etc`.

But what gets populated in your **Hello.Name** property would be `foo/id` which you'd have to detect and parse in your service.

An alternative is to supply the hidden id in a QueryString or POST'ed form parameter which you can use in ServiceStack to further populate any request DTO, e.g. using the original route:

```
 [Route("/hello/{name}")]
```

Will let you call the service with `/route/foo?id=secret` which if your Request DTO had an **id** property will be populated with `secret`. If you didn't have (or want) to have an id property you can still access the param with:

```
base.Request.QueryString["id"];
base.Request.FormData["id"];
```

But since you want this to be hidden, you should probably avoid passing it in the url which is visible by everyone (inc. web proxies, http logs, and other middle ware). A better place to hide a param is to pass it as a custom HTTP header, e.g: `X-id: secret` which you can access in your service with:

```
base.Request.Headers["X-id"];
```